# Que veut dire "adjectifs [...] qui ne s'appliquent qu'à une seule personne"?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

J'ai lu aujourd'hui la phrase suivante (qui parle de certains adjectifs latins):

> Beaucoup d'adjectifs à une seule finale n'ont point les cas de pluriel en **a** : **puber, pauper, sons, suplex, trux, inops, memor, deses,** etc., qui ne s'appliquent qu'à une seule personne. **Dives** fait **ditia** (et non *divita* ou *divitia*).

(p. 133-134, *[Grammaire de la langue latine](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFdhHTcJk3EC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=%22divita%22+%22divitia%22),* 
par J. M. Guardia and Justynian Wierzejski, 1875)

J'ai des doutes sur la signification de "ne s'appliquent qu'à une seule personne".

Je pense que les auteurs veut dire "ne s'appliquent pas aux objets inanimés". Mais pourquoi dire "ne s'appliquent qu'à une seule personne" et ne pas "ne s'appliquent qu'aux personnes"? Est-ce que la phrase "[ils] ne s'appliquent qu'à une seule personne" indique que ces adjectifs ne peuvent pas être utilisés au pluriel, même pour les personnes? (J'ai l'impression que ces adjectifs ont en effet des formes plurielles masculines et féminines.)

Comment: Notez que le texte original dit bien *qu'à UNE seule personne*.

Comment: *Qu'à une seule personne* sera effectivement compris comme *seulement à une personne et non à plusieurs personnes*. Mais en effet, l'explication avec les pluriels en -a (donc, le pluriel neutre) tend plutôt à impliquer *s'appliquent seulement aux personnes et non aux objets*. Hypothèse: il s'agirait d'un usage vieilli de *seul* (le texte a 150 ans...) ?

Comment: Oui, c'est clairement le viel usage, Il persiste parfois aujourd'hui, mais dans ce cas ce serait bien trop ambigu, et je pense que personne n'oserait dans un texte récent. La question subsidiaire, c'est de savoir si ce n'était pas (ou moins) ambigu à l'époque.

Comment: Seul reste employé en droit par exemple d'une manière similaire : tel texte ne s'applique qu'aux seules personnes morales (au lieu de : seulement aux personnes morales). Cela dit, je trouve dans mon dictionnaire de latin que pubes ou puber, puberis est appliqué par Virgile à des plantes, et que pauper existe au pluriel (pauperes) ou appliqué à … une veine (carmen vena pauperiore fluit). Désolé d'accroître la perplexité ambiante !

Answer (score 1):

> Je pense que les auteurs veut dire "ne s'appliquent pas aux objets inanimés"

je pense donc que cette interprétation est un contre-sens.

Il me semble plus logique de penser que "ne s'applique qu'à une seule personne" veut surtout dire que le nom auquel s'applique cet adjectif est singulier (dans le sens opposé de pluriel) et qu'il ne s'applique pas à des noms pluriels ou au pluriel. Non pas que le nom auquel s'applique l'adjectif soit une personne.

Qu'il existe des formes plurielles n'implique pas qu'elles soient utilisées dans le cas évoqué (hors contexte) par OP. Désolé pas de source/références, plus de contexte pourrait aider à clarifier le sens de la citation.